# Selecting alert message depending on input from user

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am trying to detect whether the user pressed the cancelButton or destructive button on the actionSheet. Depending on his/her input, I would like to modify the alert message shown on the screen.

So I tried using `if` to check the `buttonIndex`, but it turns out that the `buttonIndex` value does not change with the input from the user.

```
UIActionSheet *informUser = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Missing data" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Thanks for telling me!" destructiveButtonTitle:@"I have ignored it!" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [informUser showInView:self.view];

//        NSLog(@"Cancel button = %d", informUser.cancelButtonIndex);
//        NSLog(@"Destructive button = %d", informUser.destructiveButtonIndex);

    if(informUser.cancelButtonIndex == 1)
    {
        NSString *msg = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Pls enter the number."];

        UIAlertView *alertUser = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Missing data" message:msg delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Thanks!" otherButtonTitles:nil];

        [alertUser show];
    }
```

I also tried using a separate method:

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex;
```

but, I get wrong results when I have multiple `UIAlert` at different points on the same screen.

In short, I would like to use a different `UIAlert` for different actions/inputs from user. Therefore, how do I detect which button on the `actioSheet` has been pressed by the user?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the `UIActionSheetDelegate` and use the method:

```
– actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex:
```

The index defines which button you tapped.

If you don't want to use the button index you can get the button title of the tapped button with

```
– buttonTitleAtIndex:
```

Then you can compare the result to your button title string.

[Read more in the Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIModalViewDelegate_Protocol/UIActionSheetDelegate/UIActionSheetDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006799)

---

**Edit:**
If you want to use more actionsheets you can set the tag-value for each of them. E.g. ActionSheet1 has actionsheet.tag = 1 and so on.

Then you can switch in `– actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex:` by the tag of the given actionsheet. E.g.:

```
switch (actionsheet.tag) {
    case 1: 
        // do stuff
    break;
    case 2: 
        // do stuff
    break;
    default: break;
}
```

---

**Edit 2:**
This is a sample class that should show you the logic:

Header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIActionSheetDelegate>

@end
```

Implementation file:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UIActionSheet *as1 = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Delete" otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
    as1.tag = 0;
    as1.delegate = self;

    UIActionSheet *as2 = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title2" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel2" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Delete2" otherButtonTitles:@"Ok2", nil];
    as2.tag = 1;
    as2.delegate = self;
}


- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    switch (actionSheet.tag) {
        case 0: // as1
            switch (buttonIndex) {
                case 0:
                    // button index 0
                    break;

                case 1:
                    // button index 1
                    break;

                //....

                default:
                    break;
            }
            break;

        case 1: // as2
            switch (buttonIndex) {
                case 0:
                    // button index 0
                    break;

                case 1:
                    // button index 1
                    break;

                    //....

                default:
                    break;
            }
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: THanks for your response, E. Lüders. But what if I had more than one actionSheet. How will I detect which button has been pressed on which sheet?

Comment: So `– actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex: ` or `buttonTitleAtIndex` have to be implemented in the same block as the UIActionSheet. Correct?

Comment: Yes and you have to set the delegate of the uiactionsheet to your class (self) in order to have this methods executed

Comment: Do you mind explaining how do I set the `delegate` also? Thanks.

Comment: One min... how are you going to implement the two methods that you mentioned inside the block of UIActionSheet? I am confused at this point. If you scroll up to the code that I had pasted, `actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex` and `buttonTitleAtIndex` cannot replace `if` block.

Comment: You put that in the corresponding `case` part in my example. You can replace the switch-case with if-elseif if you want. Try to use my sample and then NSLog the tapped button index. That should help you understanding the logic and shows you which button was tapped. Then you can implement your additional logic.

Comment: I like your approach very much. But since `as1` and `as2` are in `viewDidLoad`, I cannot access them in the `- (IBAction)` methods later in the program. Can you please suggest how I can circumvent this problem?

Comment: declare them as properties in your header file: @property(nonatomic, retain)UIActionSheet *as1; Then access them with self.as1;

Comment: works like a charm! I have learnt some wonderful things along the way and I will share it as a github project once I figure out how to upload stuff to github. Thanks for your help once again, @E. Lüders.